# remove git remote branch commit

Tags: git, github

I need some assistance with Git.
So, we have a Dev and Test environment. the developers are committing using git to a 'develop' branch which is then pushed to Test environment, where the internal stakeholders will review the changes. Now, the problem is, lets say, dev team had 10 commits which are passed to Test env, where the stakeholders decided that 8 of them are ok, which will be eventually pushed to Prod. The other 2 needs to be discarded from Test env. Those discarded commits will be used sometime later, as enhancements, and as such they can stay in Dev env. until they are used.

Is there a way to do it?  Do I need to use git rebase or something like that?
Sorry if my question sounds too vague.

Comment: If the changes in the `develop` branch get published in the `Test` environment, from which branch do you publish to the `Dev` environment?

Comment: Don't merge things into develop that haven't been approved, is the real answer. Unpicking this stuff with whatever method you go for is going to result in bugs and ultimately more work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cherry pick for selecting commit to merge on dev

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do simply `interactive rebase`.

```
$ git log               # copy the commit-hash before of the commit want to discard
$ git rebase -i <commit-hash>
```

An editor will open with a list of these commit messase. Then just write `#` (comment) before the `commit-hash` you want to discard.

Answer (score 0):

1. From dev branch, you need reset those 2 discarded commits.
2. create a new branch based dev named back_commits. Since it is from dev branch, back_commits should have those 2 discarded commits, if someday you need to use these commits, just cherry pick them to whatever branch you want them in